# How to improve edge detection and remove background from an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am using the code below to remove the backroung of the images and highlight only my region of interest (ROI), however, the algorithm behaves in a wrong way in some images, discarding the stain (ROI) and deleting along with the background.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read the image and perform threshold
img = cv2.imread('photo.bmp')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Search for contours and select the biggest one
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

#Create a new mask for the result image
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

#Draw the contour on the new mask and perform the bitwise operation
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

#Display the result
cv2.imwrite('photo.png', res)
#cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly because when I run your code I do not get the output you posted (exit). If you would like to obtain only the mole it can't be done by simply thresholding because the mole is too near the border plus if you look at your image closley you will see that it has some sort of frame. However there is a simple way to do this for this image but it may not work in other cases. You can draw a fake border over your image and seperate the ROI from other noise area. Then make a threshold for which contour you wish to display. Cheers!

Example:

```
#Import all necessery libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read the image and perform threshold and get its height and weight
img = cv2.imread('moles.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Transform to gray colorspace and blur the image.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)

# Make a fake rectangle arround the image that will seperate the main contour.
cv2.rectangle(blur, (0,0), (w,h), (255,255,255), 10)

# Perform Otsu threshold.
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Create a mask for bitwise operation
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# Search for contours and iterate over contours. Make threshold for size to
# eliminate others.
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in contours:
    cnt = cv2.contourArea(i)
    if 1000000 >cnt > 100000:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [i],-1, 255, -1)


# Perform the bitwise operation.
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# Display the result.
cv2.imwrite('mole_res.jpg', res)
cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I understood, it worked. Only that images that ROI does not reach the edges does not return the stain, how to make this algorithm serve both for images that reach the edges and for images that do not reach?

Comment: Can't say from the top of my head. Have you tried this with other images? If it fails you should make a new question and give a few examples in which the code fails.